# tengo un error de este tipo: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<?php e"... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, php, html

cuando cargo mi formulario en los campos de modalidad y nivel me aparece este error de que la respuesta que se tiene no es un JSON válido, ya corrobore que mi mi código de php este ejecutando bien con la base de datos y si devuelve los datos que se solicita en este caso

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<?php

> e"... is not valid JSON
> at JSON.parse ()
> at xhr.onreadystatechange (script.js:11:37)

```
// FUNCIÓN PARA ACTUALIZAR LA LISTA DE LOS COLEGIOS
function actualizarListaColegios() {
    var modalidadSeleccionada = document.getElementById('modalidad').value;
    var nivelSeleccionado = document.getElementById('nivelEducativo').value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var colegios = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var listaColegios = document.getElementById('listaColegios');
            listaColegios.innerHTML = '';
            colegios.forEach(function(nombreColegio) {
                var opcion = document.createElement('option');
                opcion.value = nombreColegio;
                listaColegios.appendChild(opcion);
            });
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "obtenerColegios.php?modalidad=" + modalidadSeleccionada + "&nivel=" + nivelSeleccionado, true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

en el caso de mi código php tengo este

```
<?php
// Establecer encabezado de contenido como JSON

header('Content-Type: application/json');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Parámetros de conexión a la base de datos
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "school";
$username = "root";
$password = "";



// Crear conexión
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Verificar conexión
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Error de conexión a la base de datos']);
    exit; // Finalizar la ejecución del script
}

    // Obtener modalidad y nivel del query string
$modalidad = isset($_GET['modalidad']) ? $_GET['modalidad'] : '';
$nivel = isset($_GET['nivel']) ? $_GET['nivel'] : '';

// Crear la consulta SQL usando sentencias preparadas
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT nombre FROM colegios WHERE modalidad = ? AND nivel = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $modalidad, $nivel);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$colegios = [];

// Procesar el resultado
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $colegios[] = $row['nombre'];
}

// Devolver los resultados en formato JSON

echo json_encode($result);
echo json_encode($colegios);

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: El código tiene que estar en modo texto, ya que en caso de que alguien le sirva la misma solución, tendrá que escribir todo a mano.